# How do I execute sequential/parallel tasks of a workflow in Apache Spark without the use of workflow managers such as Oozie, Airflow?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My workflow consists of several tasks(Sequential and parallel) ranging from collecting data from Hbase and performing various machine learning algorithms on those data etc.

Is it possible to execute them in Apache Spark without using workflow manager? The reason I ask is I have an algorithm to order the tasks in batches (Tasks that can be run together). Can I submit them directly to Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the Spark jobs scheduling within an application: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application .

Following the configuration options mentioned above you can submit jobs (trigger jobs execution calling Spark actions) in parallel. You can apply here your algorithm `to order the tasks in batches` as well.

Keep in mind that some of your jobs can be dependent on the results of another ones running in parallel. Be sure to control the order of such jobs within your code (Spark doesn't do such kind of DAGs for you).